# Jenkins only svn:update and not svn:checkout?

Tags: svn, jenkins

Can be set in Jenkins that he did not delete all files, when I enter a new SVN URL...
Jenkins should always make an SVN update...is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the configuration page for your project you should have a `Check-out Strategy` field which you can set to `Use 'svn update' as much as possible`. I have to say, however, that performing a full checkout gives better guarantees of repeatability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I currently use it "Use 'svn update' as much as possible", but when I say use e.g. SVN Tag X, then Jenkins delets the complete workspace and than Check-out the SVN-Tag X...
The SVN Tags are similar... I do not want to wait (delet and than Check-out)... It should make only update